# Quando usar a cláusula OVER?

Tags: sql

A [Documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189461(v=sql.120).aspx) diz :

> Determina o particionamento e a ordenação do conjunto de linhas antes
>   da aplicação da função de janela associada.

Um exemplo que eu criei apenas para demonstrar isso:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cor order by carro  ) from carro
```

Este exemplo retornaria um `ROW_NUMBER` contando até mudar a condição da coluna e recomeçaria . Em uma tabela de 7 registros com 2 registros com a cor amarelo e 5 com a cor azul o `Row_Number` iria de 1 a 2 e reiniciaria e iria de 1 a 5 novamente.

Entretanto para algumas funções de agregação, não é necessário nenhum particionamento para utilizar essa condição, por exemplo este select encontrado [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle):

```
SELECT  MAX(date) OVER (ORDER BY id)
FROM    mytable
```

Mas para cláusulas com partição de valores o order by é obrigatório, mas a partição não é, fora que depende da função que está chamando, então:

- Quando devo utilizar a cláusula `OVER`?
- O `Group By` ao final de um select funciona da mesma forma(nos casos de haver partição)?
- Quando posso utilizar  funções com over sem um order by, existe funções especificas que permite isso?

Existe uma [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092120/over-clause-in-oracle) no SOEN porém achei muito genérica a resposta então continuo com algumas dúvidas.

Outras referências:

[Cláusula OVER](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql)

Comment: A resposta está na própria pergunta: função de janela. Vide artigo “Funções de janela (_window functions_)”, no **Porto SQL**: https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/14/funcoes-de-janela-window-functions/

Comment: @JoséDiz irei ver,  hoje ja tenho um conhecimento melhor e sei como usar melhor  então a explicação fará mais sentido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função `OVER` pelo o que eu entendo ela determina o particionamento e a ordenação de um conjunto de `N` linhas antes da aplicação da função de janela associada. Definindo uma janela ou conjunto de linhas especificados pelo usuário em resultados de consulta. De um modo que, compute um valor para cada linha na janela.

Você pode usar a cláusula `OVER` com funções para computar valores agregados como médias móveis, agregações cumulativas, somas acumuladas ou os primeiros N resultados por grupo.

Exemplo de sintaxe:

-Para Funções de Agregação(SUM – COUNT – AVG – etc)

```
    OVER(Partition by Campo)
```

-Para Funções de Classificação(RANK – NTILE – DENSE_RANK – ROW_NUMBER)

```
    OVER(Partition by Campo Order by Campo)
```

Agora vamos utilizá-la dentro de um `SELECT`, bora lá demonstrar solução sem `OVER` x com `OVER`

Solução COM OVER, repare que a cláusula `Partition By` funciona como se fosse um `GROUP BY`. Criando grupos, que chamamos de janelas.
Tornando a consulta mais simples.

```
SELECT Nome, Data,count(*) over(partition by Nome) TotalAcessos FROM Acesso
```

Solução senão deseja utilizar OVER

```
SELECT  A.Nome, A.Data, TabGroup.TotalAcessos
FROM  Acesso A
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  Nome, COUNT(*) TotalAcessos
    FROM  Acesso
    GROUP BY  Nome
) TabGroup ON  A.Nome=TabGroup.Nome
```